# How can I tell Valgrind to not use the default suppression file?

Tags: valgrind

I have seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579619/how-would-i-discover-the-suppressed-error-in-valgrind), but my problem is that I do not have permissions to edit the default.supp file. Is there, for example, any command line option in Valgrind that just ignores all suppression files?

Comment: did you ask the valgrind developers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Valgrind 3.10.0, there is an option for this:

```
> valgrind --default-suppressions=no ./program
```

Will ignore the default suppression file. There does not seem to be any way to do this in earlier versions.

Comment: I corrected the name of the option.  According to [the 3.10.0 release notes](http://valgrind.10908.n7.nabble.com/Valgrind-3-10-0-is-available-td51511.html), the option is named "default-suppression**s**".

Answer (score 0):

This solution might be a bit overkill, but since there is no answer yet...

You can build Valgrind on your own without requiring any root permission (just make sure to specify the `--prefix` option when running `configure` to install to some place in your home directory rather than to /usr/local). That way you can also edit the default.supp file, or maybe even build Valgrind without any default suppression file at all.